# Listview not showing response from API Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

Good day

I want to show the response from api in a listview, I have Implemented the listview but it just won't show, I don't know why. I tried different methods, wrapping it with expanded, etc but still it shows a blank page. I got response from api and implemented a model class then called it in a listview but it seems not to be working.

My code is below, may you please assist.

```
class ResultsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResultsPageState createState() => _ResultsPageState();
}

class _ResultsPageState extends State<ResultsPage> {
  List<CarDetails> objectList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //objectList = signInData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          //centerTitle: true,
          ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: objectList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                "Make",
                                //  style: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              Text(objectList[index].make.toString()),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my Car Details model class

```
class CarDetails {
  String? make;
  String? type;
  String? model;
  int? year;
  String? body;
  String? driveType;
  String? fueType;

  CarDetails(
      {this.make,
      this.type,
      this.model,
      this.year,
      this.body,
      this.driveType,
      this.fueType});

  CarDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    make = json['make'];
    type = json['type'];
    model = json['model'];
    year = json['year'];
    body = json['body'];
    driveType = json['drive_type'];
    fueType = json['fue_type'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['make'] = this.make;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['year'] = this.year;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    data['drive_type'] = this.driveType;
    data['fue_type'] = this.fueType;
    return data;
  }
}
```

API call

```
Future<void> signInData([data]) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? token = prefs.getString('token');

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('$_baseUrl/api/gateway',
          data: {
            "ClientPackageId": "0cdd231a-d7ad-4a68-a934-d373affb5100",
            "PlatformId": "ios",
            "ClientUserId": "AhmedOmar",
            "VinNumber": VINumber
          },
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
          }));
      print("data");
      print(response.data.toString());
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const ResultsPage(),
          ),
        );
      } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        // call your refresh token api here and save it in shared preference
        print(response.statusCode);
        await getToken();
        signInData(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your "objectList" is empty. that's why you see nothing on listview.

Comment: Hi, thanks, so how can I solve this?

Comment: You have to assign some data to "objectList".  follow this link : https://flutterforyou.com/how-to-fetch-data-from-api-and-show-in-flutter-listview/

Comment: I have followed this and i am getting an error here when In do this: @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    objectList = signInData();
  }.                                                                                                                                    Can you please help me how can I Integrate it to my code

Comment: Your API call doesn't return anything.

Comment: @user18309290 It does return api data, I did test it.

Comment: or you mean I should add a return statement right inside (if response.statusCode ==200)?

Answer (score 0):

your object list is empty thats why no data showing up.
Add data to the object list on your api success then it will show.
If you have any dought in that please provide your api call.

Comment: Hi @Sadhik, how do I add data to my object list on my api success?

Comment: I have provided my API call, please check my question.